# I would like to parse JSON data and post it publically on my local website, from an API

Tags: javascript, html

Currently, I am loading zomato restaurant api, and i have an api key. I am trying to POST the data through a search query after someone types an input in a form. I am running into a variety of issues regarding this project. The first issue is that I want to do this entirely locally, but im using an API, which from my understanding requires I have some backend part where the data is stored.

Is there a way for me to store the data temporarily into local storage without issues? or is my only hope with doing something without backend primarily using https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/.

Currently this is my code, and I have some divs that I want appended once the seach query is complete and the data is retrieved. Watched several videos on this subject, want to use fetch to obtain the data, but i think my code is a jumbled mess. Apologies, as its very difficult for me to find concise information about this subject.

```
``
const searchForm = document.querySelector('form');
const resultsArea = document.getElementById('#restaurant_results');


var api = 'https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/restaurant?res_id=16774318';
var city = Bethesda;
var APIkey = 'd40175980577c1cb4df25d608886594b';
var url = 

document.querySelector('.submit-btn').addEventListener('click', GetPosts);


function GetPosts (){
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        let output = '<h2>Get Posts</h2>';
        data.forEach(function(post){
            output+=`
            <div>
                <h2>${post.title}</h2>
                <p>${post.body}</p>

            </div>
            `;
        });
        document.getElementById('restaurant_results').innerHTML = output;

    })
}
```

``

``

```
  <body>
    <h1> Restaurant Finder</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
   <form action="">
   <div class="form-wrapper">
       <label for="restaurant-name">Search</label>
       <input type="restaurant-name" type="text" id="restaurant-name" placeholder="Search for a restaurant">
   </div>
   <div class="form-wrapper">
       <label for="city-name">City</label>
       <input type="city-name" type="text" id="city-name" value="Bethesda" value="New York" disabled>
   </div>
   <input type="submit" class="submit-btn">
</form>
<hr>
<section id="restaurant_results">

<div class="result_card">
    <div class="result_header">
        <h2 class="result_title">${title}</h2>
        <h3 class="result_location result_neighborhood">${neighborhood}</h3>
        <h3 class="result_location result_address">${address}</h3>
        <p class="result_price">${price}</p>
        <!--<p>${cuisine type}</p>-->
    </div>

    <div class="result_body">
    </div>
    <div class="result_footer">
        <button class="result_footer_button">Call</button>
        <button class="result_footer_button"><a href="" target="_blank" class="result_website">Visit website</a></button>
        <button class="result_footer_button">Make reservation</button>
    </div>
</div>

</section>
``
```

Comment: You don't need to store the data in the backend, you can run a simple proxy on your server.

Comment: sorry what does that mean, not familar with running a proxy or a server sorry

Comment: Does your web hosting service allow you to run PHP? https://github.com/cowboy/php-simple-proxy

Comment: i dont have a web hosting service, is it required to load data from an API? i just want to make a simply query from a form so i can show the project on my portfolio. I dont want an actual functioning website.

Comment: How do you have a web page without a server?

Comment: because im just working on it in my desktop. Or maybe I dont know what you mean by server. But im not hosting it anywhere.

Comment: Cheers for sharing your api key with us!

Comment: You can run PHP on your desktop PC. Install WAMP on Windows, XAMP on Mac.

Comment: ok, so I need to use WAMP in order to do this?

Comment: like I said I just wanted to make a project to practice search query with input field. Any comments on the actual code I posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you do not need a web server for a simple JS app that runs locally. Your code has a lot of mistakes, but main issue you are experiencing is that you defined `GetPost` after you registered event listener (`.addEventListener('click', GetPosts);`). Place `document.querySelector('.submit-btn').addEventListener('click', GetPosts);` after `GetPost` function. Also you need to prevent form from submitting (since you have no backend server to go to). You can do this by using [preventDefault()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp) method.

```js
function GetPosts(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
...
}
```

For your simple project I suggest looking into [jquery](https://jquery.com)

Remember to use `console.log` for debugging and good luck on your journey of learning JS and HTML basics.

P.S
After you get the basics, look into a proper JS framework like [react](https://reactjs.org/), [vue](https://vuejs.org/) or [angular](https://angular.io/)

Comment: thanks so much. Yes the code is riddled with errors, but I wanted to know if the first way is correct to obtain api data, or if the second way was correct. Which is why i left both on the script.js. I've seen videos doing it simply with javascript, but mainly using jsonplaceholder. Dont know how to do it with actual api data.

Comment: Here is a working example with jsonplaceholder https://jsfiddle.net/Lw7oek9r/. Real API will works exactly the same way, but you will need to pass parameters from form input.

Comment: can you explain to me what you mean by form input, and what parameters are we talking about? once I have an api key, do i load the whole url and the api key?

Comment: To query some useful results from the API you may want pass some query parameters. In your case if you are only using `restaurant` endpoint then parameters you need are `res_id` and `api-key`. These parameters are attached to url as a query string https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string. You can hardcode there parameters or get them from user input i.e text input  https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp